# How to make outside of camera view darker

Tags: camera

How do I make the outside of the camera view darker so I don't see what the camera doesn't see?

Thanks,
Rusty

Answer (score 6):

The area is called a *Passepartout* and can be adjusted for each camera.

It's under *Camera Tab > Viewport Display*

[image]